# Is it possible to build Jenkins jobs without using build numbers?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, builds

I have a job which is running very frequently, so I'd like to avoid high number of builds. Is there any way to drop job build numbers, so the job is constantly ran, but without high numbers of builds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to avoid setting the `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable, but you can avoid using it. Try using the Jenkins plugin [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin). It adds an option in your build configuration to set the build name to whatever you want, and you can ignore the `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable this way.

Consider `1.250.5` versus `1.250.${BUILD_NUMBER}`. The former will be constant no matter how many times you build and the latter will increment by one every time you build. It's also possible to use other macro values in between ${} to make more interesting dynamic build numbers.

Answer (score -3):

No, but you can just ignore it which you would be doing anyway if it wasn't there.

Comment: Answers in SE are more useful when they are not a simple yes or no but also provide some information about the subject matter.